# Model person (user) profile attributes / properties - best practice, static vs dynamic properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I couldn't easily find a relevant topic on SO so here we go - a classic problem: I have a User or Person model and I want to model that person's physical properties/attributes (eye color, hair color, skin color, gender, some lifestyle properties like sleep time per night (<8h, ~8h, >8h), smoking, daily sun exposure etc.

I usually solve that problem by creating a separate rails model (database table) for each property because then it is easy to add more options later, edit them, use as a source for `<select>`, i.e.

```
class Person
  belongs_to :eye_color
  belongs_to :skin_color
  belongs_to :hair_color
  belongs_to :sleep_per_night
  belongs_to :sun_exposure

  attr_accessible :gender # boolean, m/f
end

class HairColor
  has_many :people

  attr_accessible :value
end

class EyeColor
  has_many :people

  attr_accessible :value
end

Person.last.eye_color
...
EyeColor.first.people
```

But what if there is a lot of those attributes (i.e. 10-15 different phisycal and lifestyle properties). For me it seems like breaking DRY rule, that is, I'm left with many small tables, like `eye_colors`, which have 3-5 records. Each of those tables has only one meaningful column - value.

I was thinking how you guys solve those problems, maybe by creating a single model, i.e. PersonProperty that has the following structure

```
person_properties[type, value]
```

so the previous solution with separate models, i.e. for eye_color and hair_color would look like this (types/classes and values):

```
# PersonProperty/person_properties:
1. type: 'HairColor', value: 'red'
2. type: 'HairColor', value: 'blond'
3. type: 'SkinColor', value: 'white'
4. type: 'EyeColor', value: 'green'
5. type: 'HairColor', value: 'black'
6. type: 'SkinColor', value: 'yellow'
7. type: 'SleepPerNight', value: 'less than 8h'
8. type: 'SleepPerNight', value: 'more than 8h'
9. type: 'DailySunExposure', value: 'more than 1h'
...
19. type: 'EyeColor', value: 'blue'
...
```

The above example might be more normalized by splitting the PersonProperty model into two. Or maybe you suggest something else?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest a has_one relationship in this case. A User could `belongs_to :eye_color`, so you can map eyecolors across your users. An EyeColor `has_many :users`, so that you can do `@eye_color.users` and get all users with a specific EyeColor. Otherwise you will have to create an EyeColor for every user (or at least the ones with eyes).

The reason I'd suggest this over your PersonProperty solution is because it's easier to maintain and because of the performance gain of delegating these kinds of relations to your database.

**UPDATE:** If dynamic attributes are what you want, I'd suggest to setup your models like this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_attributes

  attr_accessible :gender
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person_attributes
end

class PersonAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person_attribute_type
  belongs_to :person_attribute_value
  belongs_to :person

  attr_accessible :person_id, :person_attribute_value_id
end

class PersonAttributeValue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_attributes
  belongs_to :person_attribute_type

  attr_accessible :value, :person_attribute_type_id
end

class PersonAttributeType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_attribute_values

  attr_accessible :name, :type
end
```

This way you can do the following:

```
@person_attribute_type = PersonAttributeType.create(:name => 'Eye color', :type => 'string')

['green', 'blue', 'brown'].each do |color|
  @person_attribute_type.person_attribute.values.build(:value => color)
end

@person_attribute_type.save

@person = Person.new
@person_attribute = @person.person_attributes.build
@person_attribute.person_attribute_value = @person_attribute_type.person_attribute_values.find(:value => 'green')
```

Of course, you probably won't fill your database through the command line. You will probably be very curious as to how this would work in a form:

```
class PersonController
  # ...
  def new
    @person = Person.new
    PersonAttributeType.all.each do |type|
      @person.person_attributes.build(:person_attribute_type = type)
    end
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(params[:person])
    if @person.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  def edit
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    PersonAttributeType.where('id NOT IN (?)', @person.person_attributes.map(&:person_attribute_type_id)).each do |type|
      @person.person_attributes.build(:person_attribute_type = type)
    end
  end
  # ...
```

*Now the form, based on Formtastic:*

```
semantic_form_for @person do |f|
  f.input :gender, :as => :select, :collection => ['Male', 'Female']
  f.semantic_fields_for :person_attributes do |paf|
    f.input :person_attribute_value, :as => :select, :collection => paf.object.person_attribute_type.person_attributes_values, :label => paf.object.person_attribute_type.name
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Mind that this all is untested, so just try to understand what I'm trying to do here.

*BTW, I now realize that the class name Person***Attribute** *is probably a bit unlucky, because you will have to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :person_attributes` which would mean you would have to `attr_accessible :person_attributes_attributes`, but you get my drift I hope.*

Comment: You could also consider dynamic properties like you're suggesting. I would, however, consider adding a model for your `property_types` and your `property_values` if you do that. So not only a `PersonProperty` table. The most important gain is that you will be able to dynamically create attributes, without having to code anything.

Comment: could you provide some simple code samples, let's say how those two tables would be related to people table and some sample records? I'm affraid that this approach may not be efficient in terms of the performance, but I'd be interested how you'd implement it.

Comment: If I understood the question right, I would probably go with this approach `parameter-parameter value` approach. You can always cache later. But to me this code seems a little too complex. There is also no `:trough` relation, but this gives pretty much the idea what needs to be done. +1 for the effort from me.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to go and I tried to be as concise as possible. You can add any `:through` relation you want of course. You can also write a method `get_all_attributes` returning a hash of attributes like so: `output = {}; person_attributes.each {|pa| output[pa.person_attribute_type.name.to_sym] = pa.person_attribute_value.value}; return output;`

Comment: Thanks Jaap, obviously the usage could be even shorter in terms of the number of characters (code) if we override .to_sym and .to_s methods for Type and Value (pa.person_attribute_value by default returning .value). I slightly modified the topic as this becomes a discussion about static vs dynamic properties.

Comment: Okay, but no one can answer that question for you, because there's not just one way to go. I generally ask myself the question how often I'd want to make changes in the attribute configuration. If the attribute requirements are pretty much static, I'd define them as such because it will perform better. If there are so many changes in the attribute configuration you'd want to be able to set them at an *application management* level, you'll want them to be dynamically configurable. `sun_exposure` seemed a bit arbitrary to me, so I just tried to give you a handle for your specific use case.